# ASP.NET MVC's Razor Engine Adding Unwanted Spaces/Whitespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I noticed that my page's navigation looked different than it should and after some inspection I found the culprit, some unwanted space(the blue highlighted line):

[image]

Then I had a Look at my _Layout.cshtml page and couldn't see anything out of the ordinary:

```
 ...
<body id="page-top">

<!-- Navigation: Called from a Partial View -->
@Html.Action("Main", "Navigation")

@RenderBody()
 ...
```

Strange thing is, When I worked on this project at home I had no issues, it's only since I downloaded my changes on TFS at work that I got the problem.

Comment: FYI, `&#65279` is a _zero width no-break space_ unicode character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:** I opened the main.cshtml file with a text editor that does not interpret Unicode characters and found the `zero width no-break space` in my code. Credits for [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) for pointing out what the `&#65279` code is.

Comment: Will accept this answer in 2 days (Cannot before that).

Comment: More importantly that is the BOM - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8 which will be why something decided to stick it on the beginning of the file.